# How Do I Select All in Selenium using Ruby on a Mac

Tags: ruby, selenium

Using: Selenium, Ruby, Mac, Chrome

Problem:  I'm trying to do a simple command 'a' to select the text in a field.

Originally I was doing a control 'a', sorry I'm new to mac.  Now that I know it's command 'a', I can't seem to find any ruby code to press the command button.

If someone can point me to a related issue, or tell me if it's actually possible, I'd appreciate it.

```
 #Example Code 
 #Change the value in the First Name Field
 #
 driver.find_element(:name,"fname").send_keys 'Bob'
 driver.find_element(:name,"fname").send_keys [:command,"a"]
 driver.find_element(:name,"fname").send_keys 'Tom'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

In windows, I will write the following code

```
driver.find_element(name: 'q').send_keys 'rajagopalan',[:control,"a"]
```

`[:control,"a"]` actually select the whole text, likewise, you may try to for mac using `[:command,"a"]`

Comment: From what I'm finding online, the [:command, "a"] does not work with a chrome browser.  I tried it with my script and didn't have any luck either.

Comment: Oh okay. Then I am sorry, I don't have any way to check for mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use Command (or Cmd) ⌘ -A from your keyboard  to select all text

Comment: Selenium is a Ruby scripting environment for the browser. The question is how to emulate what you're saying, not how to select all text.